# python lambda image error errors out as Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app'

Tags: python, docker, aws-lambda

I am deploying a lambda function as an image and the CFN stack is successful. It created the lambda function and other related resources successfully.
But when I invoke the lambda from CLI I get this error.

2023-06-08T18:11:10.111-03:00                 START RequestId: db544b2a-ff94-4c06-948f-0c4966fdc335 Version: $LATEST
2023-06-08T18:11:10.112-03:00                 [ERROR] Runtime.ImportModuleError: Unable to import module 'app': No module named 'BasePage' Traceback (most recent call last):
2023-06-08T18:11:10.114-03:00                 END RequestId: db544b2a-ff94-4c06-948f-0c4966fdc335

Under “the_python_code” dir, there are few python files and classes but the handler function is just the below few lines of code and I am not referring to any other classes from “the_python_code” dir.

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

logger.info('In app.py...')

def my_lambda_handler(event, context) -> None:
    logger.info('Inside lambda_handler...')
```

My local python env is 3.9 and my Dockerfile base image is also 3.9.My Dockerfile looks like this.

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/python:3.9
ENV PYTHONPATH=${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
WORKDIR ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN pip3 install --no-cache-dir \
--trusted-host pypi.org \
--trusted-host pypi.python.org \
--trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
--upgrade pip

COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
# Copy function code
COPY ./app.py ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
COPY ./the_python_code/ ${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}/
CMD [ "app.my_lambda_handler" ]
```

I also have **init**.py inside all the sub-folders under "the_python_code" directory.
I am invoking the lambda image from CLI as

```
aws lambda invoke --function-name dev-poc-lambda-image-dtx-v1 outfile.txt
```

Any help is much appreciated.